# Scope of Variables declared within javascript object

Tags: javascript

I was trying to understand the scope of variables in javascript objects. But the behavior that I am getting seems to be a little off the road. To put it simply, if I have an object that defines a function as a variable, then the function variable is not able to access other variables of the object in which it is defines. The code below will make things clear.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var someObject = {
            someVariable : 5,
            getVariable: function() {
                return someVariable;
            }
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            alert(someObject.getVariable());
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Hello There
</body>
</html>
```

The above code gives **"ReferenceError: someVariable is not defined"** for the someVariable in function getVariable(). Would anyone like to comment on this behavior?

Comment: In your code `someObject` is a variable that points to an object. But `someVariable` is the name of a property on that object.  Variables and object properties are very different things.

Comment: Property resolution and identifier resolution are very different things. The first is resolved as properties of an Object and proceeds along the `[[Prototype]]` chain, stopping at `null`. The second is resolved as local parameters of an execution context and proceeds along the scope chain, which is a sequence of execution contexts ([Lexical Environments](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2)) stopping at the global object.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

The "variable" you're talking about isn't a "variable", it's a `property` of an object (the object happening to be a variable).

As such, you have two options.
Assuming that your object is made like this:

```
var obj = {
    property : 42,
    everything : function () { /* ... */ }
};
```

The two options for inside of your function body, to return the value 42 are:

```
obj.property;
```

OR

```
this.property;
```

When you call:

```
obj.everything();
```

The JS interpreter will see `obj` as being equal to `this` inside of the function.
Or you reference `obj` itself, directly, and access `property` using either `.property` dot-notation, or `["property"]` bracket-notation.

Comment: `this` will reference the object only if the function is called in a way that sets its `this` to be the object (e.g. `obj.everything()`). The function can be called so that its `this` is a reference to any object (or in strict mode, any value), even `null` or `undefined`, e.g. `var x = obj.everything; x();`.

Comment: Absolutely. Dynamic resolution of `this` and its late-binding are, I felt a little too far down the path for somebody becoming familiar with object properties, on the ground floor. While it can be a powerful tool, AND has to be carefully guarded for things like callbacks (where pre-emptive binding becomes important), I think just the warning that `x = obj.func; x();` throwing horrible errors is enough for now.

Comment: I don't see that warning. Your answer (and others) introduce `this` when the question was about confusion over the difference between identifier resolution of environment variables vs object properties. The simple answer is to use `return someObject.someVariable;` and leave `this` out of it. But that horse has bolted. :-)

Comment: I agree with @RobG. You should generally avoid `this` since its value depends on the execution context. It might work for one-off uses, just as the `obj.property` construct. However, if this is supposed to be a general usage form, then one should define a class instead and she will not have the problem in the first place.

Comment: @RobG, Norgaurd You are absolutely correct about using someObject.someVariable instead of "this.someVariable". As you pointed out, this.someVariable will work only when the getVariable is invoked directly on someObject. Although, I couldn't really understand the technical explanations, I still now get a hang of it.   Thanks all for sharing your experiences and ideas.

Comment: Yes, and personally, I leave `this` out of my own programs as often as possible, unless I am actively looking for the benefits of late-binding (say in a service/ent-like situation, using `call`s, if someone else really insisted that their modules be written "classically"). That said, the literally-declared singleton is really the prototypical general-usecase where older, beginner-OOP tutorials display `this`. And trying to introduce it in a harmless way, in a simple scenario, I believe is better than not addressing it at all, given that it very much exists everywhere else out there.

Comment: @RobG The warning got edited out, before I submitted (go me), apparently, but your warning in comment-1 still perfectly makes up for it, in terms of bare-minimum usage. @Nirvan for purposes of variable definition: `var bob = "bob";` `var person = { name : "Bob" };` `var person={}; person.name = "Bob";` #2 and #3 produce the same end-result. But at no point is there a globally-available `name` variable. If you want `person.name;`, you have to refer to it as such. `this` is a special keyword inside of functions which points to whatever is *one dot* ahead of the function you're calling (usually)

Comment: There are many exceptions to this, especially if you want to get into all of the corners of the technical aspects. But basically, at the moment you call the function, JS looks at what object you're calling the function on (or `window` in ES3-mode and `undefined` in ES5-mode if no object is specified), and uses that object.  So you could write two objects like: `var obj1 = { name : "Bob", say : function () { console.log(this.name); } }, obj2 = { name : "Doug" }; obj2.say = obj1.say;` In this case, when you call `obj2.say`, `this` points to `obj2.name;`. But you'll get an error if `this`

Comment: ends up being `undefined` (eg: `var say = obj1.say; say();`), because `undefined.name;` doesn't exist, and asking for properties of `null` or `undefined` throws errors. This is the reason I don't recommend using `this`, unless you know (and want) what's going on, in a particular code design. If you use `this` inside of callbacks, unless you know how to bind scope, you're going to be very frustrated. But nonetheless, this is what `this` is, and there are legitimate uses for it, but knowing its downsides before going crazy with it is for the best.

Comment: @Norguard—I think `this` can best be thought of as a special parameter passed to a function other than as an argument. It's really there for inheritance, but is useful as it can be set by the call without having to explicitly pass the object — except for `call`, `apply` and `new` of course. Don't exceptions prove the rule? :-)

Comment: @RobG I personally think about it in the same fashion as scope-resolution, except with only two stops (immediate parent of assignment and `window||undefined`). The only exceptions are to override with `.call||.apply` or to enclose, using `.bind || that = this;`. Of course, to think about context-resolution in that way, you need to be comfortable with scope-resolution (and ideally closures) in general.

Comment: Don't do that, `this` is entirely different to scope. It will never be resolved beyond the current execution context and is always set on entering the context. It's simply a local variable that is set by how a function is called, not by where it is called from or how it's declared, initialised or created (ignoring *bind*), which is why it should not be called "context" either.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply the **same** scope, but a second, dynamically-interpreted (JIT) context, expressly for `this`, based upon the parent of the assignment (as without overrides like `call` or `bind`, or reassignment, the context of `this` isn't going to change if you assign it to a thing and call it from the same thing. A callback, for example: you assign it as a parameter to a function, that parameter has no explicit parent, thus `window||undefined` necessitating binding/overriding of `this` context.

Comment: A function within a function is likewise not a property of an explicit object. Meanwhile, you could create something like `function sayName () { console.log(this.name); }` and assign a reference to the function to properties of a dozen different "people", and calling it from any one of those people will then work as-expected. Reassignment from any one of those people to anything else follows the same stipulations as before, as you're either passing a reference to another object's property, directly, or you need to bind/override `this` context.

Comment: Thinking about it like an invisible parameter works (an invisible call to `.call`), but how is that easily-remembered when dealing with async or function inside function contexts, while generalizing the concept for others to use? A lot of people instinctively assume that `this` inside of the outer function is passed to the inner function implicitly, for example, and without clarification of when `this` is and isn't passed, will hit snags. Regardless of what the engine does behind the scenes, `object.method();` and `function (param) { param(); }` behave predictably, based on their assignments.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a variable, that is a property/field of an object.

Try `this.someVariable`.

Here `this` is a (rather special) variable that points to the object, and the dot (or square bracket) syntax can be used to access fields of that object.

You can also do `someObject.someVariable` in places where `someObject` (another variable pointing at the object) is in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.someVariable`:

```
var someObject = {
        someVariable: 5,
        getVariable: function () {
            return this.someVariable;
        }
    };

window.onload = function () {
    alert(someObject.getVariable());
};
```

Comment: You are correct, but basically I was trying to understand why adding "this" works? Why can't the function access the someVariable directly as it seems to be in scope of the function.

Comment: @Nirvan Because it's not a variable, but a property of the object.

Comment: @Nirvan—using `this` only works if the function is called in a way that sets its `this` as a reference to `someObject`, e.g. `someObject.getVariable()`. It will not work (for example) if assigned as a listener: `someElement.onclick = someObj.getVariable` as in that case, when the function is called by the handler, its `this` will be set to the element.